# GROUPING ORDER BY - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 fields, say:

```
roll varchar(100)

marks int (10) // can be 0 5 or 10

time anyTimeFormat

//time stores the time of passing the exam.
```

What I need to do is to sort in ascending order, the time of completion, which I am able to do by

```
ORDER by time ASC
```

However, I need to sort in ascending order, and at the same time, group records, based on marks, i.e. those who have scored 10 and were the first to complete, and so on.

I tried GROUP BY, but know that it won't work. Any help on this is welcomed.

**NOTE:** I use mysql. PHP is the front end.

**Sample Data**:

```
roll        marks        time

1             10          2012-09-07 15:03:39
2             10          2012-09-07 15:03:42
3             10          2012-09-07 15:03:17
4             10          2012-09-07 15:03:20
5              5          2012-09-07 15:03:11
```

**Expected Output:**:

```
// I want those with 10 marks to be displayed first.

roll        marks        time

1             10          2012-09-07 15:03:17
2             10          2012-09-07 15:03:20
3             10          2012-09-07 15:03:39
4             10          2012-09-07 15:03:42
5              5          2012-09-07 15:03:11
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using? sql server, mysql, oracle?  please also post some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
ORDER BY marks DESC, time ASC
```

Or in other words, you sort on marks because you want the highest marks first, then for equivalent marks, sort by time in order to show first completers first.

Comment: Thanks. What if, I replace marks by a field, 'status', that shows whether a test has been attended, skipped and so on? That is, how do I deal when the field is non numeric?

Comment: Just convert it to a number defining how you want the status to be sorted in respect to other status values. Any data type can be sorted, so you could also choose status values, which sorts nicely (for instance, use a char, 'A' for attended and 'S' for skipped).